# TransferValue - implicit converter produced <null> in TreeView ItemsSource

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, treeview, reactiveui

For some reason, the value is created correctly and then rejected by some "implicit converter", and I can't figure out why. Here's a quick overview of the code, but first the diagnostics messages:

```
System.Windows.Data Warning: 95 : BindingExpression (hash=63646052): Got PropertyChanged event from MainViewModel (hash=17472816)
System.Windows.Data Warning: 101 : BindingExpression (hash=63646052): GetValue at level 0 from MainViewModel (hash=17472816) using RuntimePropertyInfo(TestNodeRoot): HierarchicalTestNode (hash=53650690)
System.Windows.Data Warning: 80 : BindingExpression (hash=63646052): TransferValue - got raw value HierarchicalTestNode (hash=53650690)
System.Windows.Data Warning: 84 : BindingExpression (hash=63646052): TransferValue - implicit converter produced <null>
System.Windows.Data Warning: 89 : BindingExpression (hash=63646052): TransferValue - using final value <null>
```

Next is the tree view binding. Tracing is enabled, as you can see:

```
    <TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding TestNodeRoot, diag:PresentationTraceSources.TraceLevel=High}">
        <TreeView.Resources>
            <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type models:HierarchicalTestNode}" ItemsSource="{Binding Children, diag:PresentationTraceSources.TraceLevel=High}">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
            </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
        </TreeView.Resources>
    </TreeView>
```

The `TestNodeRoot` binding is to an `ObservableAsPropertyHelper<HierarchicalTestNode?>` in the view model which is wired to the `Solution` property changing (note that this works, because the binding gets this value, as seen above):

```
    readonly ObservableAsPropertyHelper<HierarchicalTestNode?> testNodeRoot;
    public HierarchicalTestNode? TestNodeRoot => testNodeRoot.Value;

    this.WhenAnyValue(x => x.Solution).Select(s => s is null ? null : HierarchicalTestNode.Create(s.TestNodes!))
        .ToProperty(this, x => x.TestNodeRoot, out testNodeRoot);
```

And lastly the `HierarchicalTestNode` is a simple `ReactiveObject` that holds properties (note the `Children` property is an observable collection as expected by the XAML `HierarchicalDataTemplate`, though I didn't get there):

```
public class HierarchicalTestNode : ReactiveObject
{
    string name;
    public string Name { get => name; set => this.RaiseAndSetIfChanged(ref name, value); }

    bool cloak;
    public bool Cloak { get => cloak; set => this.RaiseAndSetIfChanged(ref cloak, value); }

    int displayIndex;
    public int DisplayIndex { get => displayIndex; set => this.RaiseAndSetIfChanged(ref displayIndex, value); }

    TestNodeType nodeType;
    public TestNodeType NodeType { get => nodeType; set => this.RaiseAndSetIfChanged(ref nodeType, value); }

    public ObservableCollection<HierarchicalTestNode> Children { get; } = new();

    // other stuff for creating it from a flat database, this also works
}
```

So any idea what that internal converter is trying to do? I don't think the `TreeView` is expecting any specific kind of class from what I've seen online, and I'm not passing interfaces (I read that that could cause issues), so what's wrong?

Comment: An ItemsSource Binding expects a source property that is an IEnumerable or can be converted to an IEnumerable. Is that true for HierarchicalTestNode, i.e. for the ItemsSource Binding on the TreeView? Or did you intend to write `ItemsSource="{Binding TestNodeRoot.Children}"`?

Comment: Oh man I knew it had to be something dumb... No, the idea was to have a tree with a single root node. Let me give it a quick try, but you're most likely correct.

Answer (score 0):

As Clemens pointed out in his comment, the issue is that even though I have only one root node, the `ItemsSource` property expects an enumerable. Converting the root to an array of one item solved my problem.